# Why association pattern unmatched when using variable

Tags: pattern-matching, associations

I have association and want to replace integer in specific element in this association. I'm trying to build pattern to be used by `ReplaceAll` command. When number is explicitly provided in pattern match occurs, but when I put number in a variable and provide number from variable match fails.

```
In[1]:= MatchQ[<|id -> 6, dur -> 10, skill -> 1, succ -> {7}, 
  dl -> 250|>, <|la___, succ -> {l___, 7, r___}, ra___|>]

Out[1]= True

In[2]:= last = 7
last[[0]]

Out[2]= 7

Out[3]= Integer

In[4]:= MatchQ[<|id -> 6, dur -> 10, skill -> 1, succ -> {7}, 
  dl -> 250|>, <|la___, succ -> {l___, last, r___}, ra___|>]

Out[4]= False
```

As shown in this example first match occurs, but second fails with number in variable.

Comment: It is probably because, `Association` as the attribute `HoldAllComplete`. You work around this with `pat = With[{last = last}, <|la___, succ -> {l___, last, r___}, ra___|>];
MatchQ[<|id -> 6, dur -> 10, skill -> 1, succ -> {7}, 
  dl -> 250|>, pat]`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher yeap, it works! I even managed to perform `ReplaceAll` operation with this pattern

Comment: I can accept this as answer if nobody will provide "cleaner" solution

Answer (score 8):

You may use [`KeyValuePattern`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KeyValuePattern.html).

With

```
assoc = <|id -> 6, dur -> 10, skill -> 1, succ -> {7}, dl -> 250|>;
last = 7;
```

then the following return `True`.

```
MatchQ[assoc, KeyValuePattern[succ -> {___, last, ___}]]

MatchQ[assoc, KeyValuePattern[(succ -> v_List) /; MemberQ[v, last]]]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this, but there is problem when I try to perform `ReplaceAll` operation. I need to make something like this: ```list /. <|la___, succ -> {l___, last, r___}, ra___|> :> <|la, succ -> {l, r}, ra|>}```

Comment: Is possible to do replace with `KeyValuePattern`?

Comment: @АлексейПесчаный I would go with `Query`. Something like `Query[{Key[succ] -> DeleteCases[last]}]@assoc`.  Note that you should ask for what you need help with instead of what you think you need to solve what you need help with; This is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) question.

Answer (score 7):

*Turning my comment into an answer.*

It is probably because `Association` has the attribute `HoldAllComplete`: You can see that from the fact that the `last` in the pattern expression stays unevaluated.

You can work around this with

```
last= 7;
pat = With[{last = last}, <|la___, succ -> {l___, last, r___}, ra___|>];     
MatchQ[<|id -> 6, dur -> 10, skill -> 1, succ -> {7}, dl -> 250|>, pat]
```